# "pointer being freed was not allocated" in structure

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, delete-operator

I have defined a structure containing a bytes array and its length. The destructor should only delete the byte array if it was dynamically instanced by the structure's constructor. But sometimes, the `delete array;` instruction fails with error `pointer being freed was not allocated`. It seems really strange as the array was instanced in the structure. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

```
typedef unsigned char byte_t;
struct bytes_t {
    bytes_t(varint_t c) : array(new byte_t[c]), count(c), alloc(true) {}
    bytes_t(byte_t b[], varint_t c) : array(&b[0]), count(c), alloc(false) {}
    ~bytes_t() {
        if (alloc)
            delete array;
    }

    byte_t* array;
    varint_t count;
    bool alloc;
};
```

**Edit:** Changed a little bit my code, but it still seems to fail. It works when called from the main thread, but not from another thread.

```
class bytes_t {
private:
    byte_t* const array_;
    const varint_t count_;
    const bool alloc_;
public:
    bytes_t(varint_t c) : array_(new byte_t[c]), count_(c), alloc_(true) {}
    bytes_t(byte_t* b, varint_t c) : array_(b), count_(c), alloc_(false) {}
    ~bytes_t() {
        if (alloc_)
            delete[] array_;
    }
    byte_t* getArray() {
        return array_;
    }
    varint_t getCount() {
        return count_;
    }
};
```

**Edit:** I followed @Jens' advice and used `std::vector` instead. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues in your class:

- When you allocate an array with new[], you must call delete[] instead of delete
- Your class needs a copy-constructor and a copy-assignment operator
- The class has only public members which provide a very poor abstraction and no information hiding. You should make the members private and provide a public interface for clients.

Have you considered using `std::vector` instead of writing your own implementation?

Comment: You're right, thank you. `std::vector` will do the job better than my structure. But, just for the sake of curiosity, I'd still like to know why is this error occurring.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example which reproduces the error? Otherwise, there are many reasons for problems. I listed some of them, e.g. copying the object results in double deletes, everything is public so other code can manipulate alloc and put the object in a wrong state, wrong delete ...